# Passing mandatory data to super classes in Kotlin

Tags: constructor, kotlin, superclass

I've got an issue creating entities in Kotlin. In particular, it's about passing data to a super class. Find an example below.

I've got an abstract super class called `Trackable` that classes can extend. It has a `user` property that stores who has created that particular object.

```
abstract class Trackable(
  var createdBy: User
) : Persistable()
```

An class called `Contract` would now implement the `Trackable` super class with a compile-time error for the time being:

```
@Entity
data class Contract(
  var creationDate: LocalDateTime
) : Trackable() // compile error, no user passed here
```

So, as the `User` is a mandatory field in `Trackable`, I have to pass a `User` object to the `Trackable` constructor. What came first into my mind was creating a transient property called `creator` that I pass on to the `Trackable`.

```
@Entity
data class Contract(
  @Transient val creator: User,
  var creationDate: LocalDateTime
) : Trackable(creator)
```

However, domain-wise this seems to be a very dirty solution as it pollutes my `Contract`.

Having started with Kotlin recently I'm still lacking of appropriate and reasonable patterns to use. Could anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: What do you mean with: "it pollutes my Contract"?

Comment: I mean that every constructor parameter I add to a `data` prefixed class will generate a class property with a respective getter. And I just want the class to contain properties that belong to it, not those I just need to pass on to the `Trackable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data classes don't work best with inheritance, it might be better to use composition, but if you really want to use inheritance then IMHO best way to do it is following:

Declare abstract class with abstract fields:

```
abstract class Trackable : Persistable(){
    abstract var createdBy: User

}
```

Extend abstract class and override property inside data class:

```
data class Contract(
        override var createdBy: User,
        var creationDate: LocalDateTime) : Trackable()
```

This way you avoid having duplicate property while having ability to access that property from `parent` class but it is actually a member of `children`, from my perspective this is best solution as you keep all benefits of `data class`, but take it with grain of salt as it is subjective.

Comment: I don't really need to use inheritance, I'm just used to for that particular issue I have. Thanks a lot for the suggestion to solve it by inheritance, but I guess it's more reasonable to rethink in different patterns, e.g. composition, as you've quoted, too.