# Local parameters in Kotlin's primary constructor of a data class

Tags: constructor, kotlin, data-class

Regarding `data` classes it is forbidden to **not** use `var` or `val` keywords in the primary constructor, i.e. *every* parameter is implicitly turned into a class property. However, sometimes there are cases which I don't want each parameter to be turned into a class property.

So, as far as I can see, there is no chance of passing a parameter in a primary constructor that is accessible only within the constructor and is forgotten after the construction of the instance has finished. Is there a good reason for this?

The only way I see to get around this, is **not** to use `data` classes or to use a secondary constructor that allows for non-var/val-prefixed variables. However, having a lot of parameters that need to be passed, a secondary constructor would immensely inflate the class. Of course, I could wrap all the parameters into another object, but that would just kind of shift the problem to another place.

Is there a recommended approach or pattern in order to cope with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not limited at all, you just have to do things a bit differently.

Data classes are intended to be very clear about what they contain and in what order, and only allow members in the **primary constructor** parameter list.

But you have other options: use a **secondary constructor**, and/or **create top-level functions** with the same name as the class with different overloads, or create **factory methods** in the companion object:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {
    // secondary constructor
    constructor (name: String): this(name, 0) {
       // ... make a newborn
    }

    // factory methods in companion object
    companion object {
        fun of(name: String, birthdate: LocalDate): Person {
            return Person(name, yearsSince(birthdate))
        }
    }
}

// function with same name as class acting like a constructor
fun Person(name: String, birthdate: LocalDate): Person {
    return Person(name, yearsSince(birthdate))
}

// these all work now:

Person("Fred", 30)                                  // primary constructor
Person("Baby")                                      // secondary constructor
Person("Geoff", LocalDate.parse("12/08/1990"))      // top-level function
Person.of("Jennifer", LocalDate.parse("01/01/1981") // companion function
```

You can also hide the primary constructor by making it private, but you cannot hide the `copy` version of that constructor.

By the way, having data classes with this contract for the primary constructor really help serialization/deserialization libraries know what to do with the class that would be guesswork otherwise.  It is a good thing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate examples.

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing that I must say is that this is my personal opinion so take it with grain of salt.

From official kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

> We frequently create classes whose main purpose is to hold data. In such a class some standard functionality and utility functions are often mechanically derivable from the data.

So `data classes` are supposed to be used as data holders, and they shouldn't contain much logic.

From my perspective when you want to pass something to constructor but class doesn't store that data then there is probably some logic connected with that.

Common situation when you want to do this is:

1. Using some flag to change behavior of constructor
2. Passing some class that wraps all data needed and then extract it to each individual field.

In first case then we clearly see that this isn't part of `data class` use case.

And second case is simply bad code, it introduces unneeded dependency on another class and hides what that class actually needs.

Constructors should be simple, they take data that class requires and bind it to fields, not much logic should reside there, it should be up to those that use constructor to prepare all data, and if there is some repeatable code when creating new instances then it might be good idea to use `factory method` to encapsulate that.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting insights. There is a third case where you would want to pass objects to a super class constructor. We both have recently discussed that in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572331/passing-mandatory-data-to-super-classes-in-kotlin. I do like your suggestion using factory methods.

Comment: Oh right, well there is that case too, still its kinda solved using overriding approach I mentioned there, `data classes` have a bit odd behavior because they are meant to be used only as simple data containers as their name suggests, for cases in which you need some logic there are always regular `classes`